# Set IE11 compatibility mode via HTML

Tags: .net, asp-classic, internet-explorer-11

Is there any way of setting the compatibility mode of IE11 through HTML on a page? I have a webpage that contains lots of older specially made components that dont do that well with Internet Explorer 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a meta tag to choose the exact type of rendering engine you want IE to use, for example:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=5">
```

Full information and options can be found at the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Is this really equivalant to setting compabilitymode in IE11? I get errors while setting this that I dont get in compabilitymode?

Comment: I think compatibility mode on IE11 uses IE7. I put IE5 in the code above as an example, there are several options described in the link to choose from to suit your exact situation.

Answer (score 1):

Polynomial's answer is close. Should be: content="IE=EmulateIE7"

See the following link for how to enable this site-wide in IIS or in web.config: http://blog.codefluententities.com/2012/09/28/how-to-enable-ie-9-compatibility-mode-for-your-website/